# Thumb selection and form field submitted as GET or POST

Tags: php, html

I want the user to select a thumbnail (which the browser will list from a specific folder) and write comments in a text box and then submitted.

Any ideas which way I should go for? Initially I thought to put thumb selection in PHP Variable but that seems not possible.

Comment: this is not an coding service..  please post your coding what you are tried ?

Comment: What you have tried so far ....?

Comment: @Arun I am not asking for the code, just the idea whether I should use Radio Buttons for thumb selection or is there any other way.